# I need to write an If statement that will print a message if any character inputted is contained within a string

Tags: java, string, character, java.util.scanner

Say that I need to input a series of letters for the value: letter.

And I have multiple strings such as String.s1 that contains the characters: ABC

And String.s2 is DEF and so on and so on until the end of the alphabet.

I need to write an If statement so that if I input any character from s1 it will return with the digit 1 and s2 will return the digit 2 and so on and so on. I need to be able to input all the characters I need at once.

My current messy code is:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Assign2 {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char letters;
    int numbers;
    String.s1 = "ABC";
    String.s2 = "DEF";
    String.s3 = "GHI";
    String.s4 = "JKL";
    String.s5 = "MNO";
    System.out.print("Enter the chosen letter: ");
    letters = input.letters();
    if (letters.contains(s1))
      numbers = 1;
    else if (letters.contains(s2))
      numbers = 2;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not helpful to answer your question. There are a number of ways to do this in many languages. - If you can update your question with some code or any attempt you have already made in solving your issue, it would help to answer your question.

Comment: import java.util.Scanner;



 public class Assign2 {



  public static void main(String[] args) {

   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  char letters;
  int numbers;
  String.s1 = "ABC";
  String.s2 = "DEF";
  String.s3 = "GHI";
  String.s4 = "JKL";
  String.s5 = "MNO";
  System.out.print("Enter the chosen letter: ");
  letters = input.letters();
  if (letters.contains(s1))
   numbers = 1;
   else if (letters.contains(s2))
   numbers = 2;
   
  

  

  

 }

}

Comment: Thanks, Java is not a language I'm familiar with but I've added tags to your post to specify the language and help others who are familiar find your post and hopefully help.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a string array such as `yourArray` below that holds `s1,s2,s3` so on. Then you can handle this in a simple loop

```
for(int i = 0; i< yourArray.size ; i++){

  if(letters.contains(yourArray[i])){
     numbers = i+1;
     break;
   }

}
```